# How to create gradient blur in HTML & CSS?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, blur, linear-gradients

I have Layout.js which has Navigationbar inside navigation bar is just unordered list of list items

```
function Layout(props) {
    return <div>
        <NavigationBar />
        <main className={classes.main}>
            {props.children}
        </main>
    </div>
}
```

navbar.module.css is

```css
.container {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    ..
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(37, 47, 81, 0.6),rgba(37, 47, 81, 0));
    backdrop-filter: blur(3px);
    ..
    
}
```

I want `backdrop-filter: blur` to be linear gradient as color because now it's just line where its starts to blur. Can someone help me easily fix this?

I tried webkit but it write warning that it is not supported by browsers.

Comment: Maybe instead of `top: 0` use  `inset: 0`. Shorthand for `top,right,bottom,left`. Place a [reprex]...